# Swift : Main.Storyboard localization failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, storyboard

I'm working on Xcode 7.3.1 and trying to **set localization for my project.** I tried to **localized Main.storyboard file**

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

The second screenshot shows Main.storyboard is localized. However, this is not reflected in Main.Storyboard (screenshot 1). It should be like in screenshot 3.

[image: Screenshot 3]

Note : Main.Storyboard file contains around 10 scenes.

Whats fix?

Comment: you are in the correct way

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Then where to write translated value for controls i.e. "uJE-ia-usa.text" = "Hindi-Text";

Comment: I added  the answer check once bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**step-1**

select your stroyboard  --> go to file Inspector --> localization --> enable the tick mark for your language

you get the output of like

[image]

**Step-2**

finaly you get the output like

[image]

Comment: can you send the project I will Do this

Comment: @Anbu.kartik : Confidential project..cannot share it

Comment: @JayprakashDubey - ok bro, remove tick mark in base on file inspector and add again once

Comment: @Anbu.Kartik : That one solved my problem. Thanks! Really that was simple. I was stuck for more than 2 hours..

Comment: @JayprakashDubey - happy to hear bro

Answer (score 1):

You should write `Classes` for your `controls` used in `XIB OR Storyboard` `Views` & assign the `Classes` to respective control types like this -

```
class LocalizedTextField: UITextField {

    override func drawPlaceholderInRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let localizedPlaceHolder = self.placeholder!.localized
        self.placeholder = localizedPlaceHolder
        super.drawPlaceholderInRect(rect)
    }
}
class LocalizedLabel : UILabel {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        if let text = text {
            self.text = text.localized
            self.bounds.size.width = CGFloat.max
            self.sizeToFit()
        }
    }
}

class LocalizedButton : UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        for state in [UIControlState.Normal, UIControlState.Highlighted, UIControlState.Selected, UIControlState.Disabled, UIControlState.Focused] {
            if let title = titleForState(state) {
                setTitle(title.localized, forState: state)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension String {

    var localized: String {
        let localizedValue =  NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
        if localizedValue == "" {

            return self
        }
        else
        {
            return localizedValue
        }
        return self

    }
}
```

[image]